# Type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => RestaurantScreen(restaurant: restaurant),
  ),
),
```

Above on the OnTap, when I say context it says the error below. Is there a workaround for this?

```
The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'
```

Comment: If you need main file tell

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assignsed to the parameter type 'Build context'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly possible that you've imported by mistake the `dart:js` module. If so, just remove it:

```dart
import 'dart:js'; // <- Remove this import
```

[The `dart:js` module exports a global `context` of type `JsObject`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-js/context.html) and its type conflicts with the `BuildContext`.

---

On the other hand, if importing 'dart:js' in on purpose, then [`BuildContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html), the `context`, is only available inside a [`StatefullWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) or just inside the [`StatelessWidget.build(context)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget/build.html) method. Other places also pass `context` as a function parameter.

It looks like you're trying to use `context` in an outside function/class. So, to fix the problem pass the `context` as a parameter to the function/method being called.

Comment: Did you import the `dart:js` by mistake? Remove it if so.

Comment: Nice to hear that. I've updated the answer with this info too. And if this is the solution remember to accept the answer ✅ right below the up/down ▲/▼ vote so others know this solved it for you.